# Transition animation for Android using Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, material-design

Is it possible to implement the transition animation below for Android using Xamarin Forms?

What I have is this [how to](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition) for Android. I tried to implement it with custom renderers but got stuck when I needed to configure the Intent. Also, I read Forms apps run on a single Intent.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a plugin to make this type of transitions in xamarin forms (for ios and android).

The key is to use a custom NavigationPage. In iOS, you need to implement IUINavigationControllerDelegate and IUIGestureRecognizerDelegate, in Android its easier: just override the SetupPageTransition method.

You can find all the source code here:
https://github.com/Evolutionlab/Xamarin.Plugin.SharedTransitions

Here the Nuget package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Plugin.SharedTransitions/

P.S.

Yes, on Android Xamarin forms use a single activity. The NavigationPage use Fragments to navigate between pages.

Comment: Whether you answer a question that was asked 9 years or 9 days ago, it's fine. You don't need to explicitly state that you know the thread is old, because the question age isn't really important if changes to a language, library, or framework make old answers obsolete, or make it possible for actual or alternative solutions (depending on the problem).

Answer (score 0):

The key point is that do the Xamarin.Form have the similar function "MakeSceneTransitionAnimation"?

As my point of view:

U can use

```
PushAsync(Page page, Animation animation)
```

to defined your page animation as the gif shows.

When the new page init u should use the

```
MyImageControl.TranslateTo(-100,-100, 1000);
```

To defined the control animation.