# How to implement connected animation in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, uwp

In UWP you can create great tansitions on page navigation:
[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/connected-animation

Even flutter has something similar:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations

How can we create such thing on Xamarin?

Comment: Since connected animations are UWP specific functionality you will need to implement it in the Xamarin.UWP project,the approach is similar to how platform specific notifications are implemented.

Comment: I gave the name as an example. I want something similar. I see it can be done on Android too https://material.io/design/navigation/navigation-transitions.html not sure about ios

Comment: @Ateik Xamarin does support animations within a view/page but not across pages. You would need to implement it yourself.

Comment: It wont be perfect to implement in in a page level.

Comment: If you plan on doing it on each platform separatly, the Microsoft community toolkit might be helpful for the UWP one : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/animations/connectedanimations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something similar to this:

> Shared element transitions are animations connecting common elements from one page to another.
>   A shared element transition determines how elements that are present in two pages transition between them. For example, an image that is displayed on both Page A and Page B, transitions from A to B when B becomes visible.

This is description of this [1] xamarin plugin, which is also available here [2].

I found it here [3].

**Sources:**

[1] https://github.com/GiampaoloGabba/Xamarin.Plugin.SharedTransitions

[2] https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Plugin.SharedTransitions/

[3] [Transition animation for Android using Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622967/transition-animation-for-android-using-xamarin-forms?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I wanted. I wish I can give you more points :)